# How to get Tweets in Appwrite using flutter

Tags: flutter, twitter, riverpod, appwrite

Currently working with Appwrite, and I'm trying to simulate my app to Twitter App where users can follow and unfollow each other.

At the moment, users can create tweet, like tweet, comment on tweet, follow and unfollow each other but I want to be able to fetched tweet of users I'm following, I don't want to pull all the tweets to the user, only the person they are following.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of users the user is following and every tweet has a userId attribute, you can do something like:

```dart
final List<string> following = ['userId1', 'userId2'];
databases.listDocuments(
  databaseId: '[DATABASE_ID]',
  collectionId: '[COLLECTION_ID]',
  queries: [
    Query.equal('userId', following),
  ],
);
```

This is documented [here](https://appwrite.io/docs/queries#building-queries).

Note: there are some limitations to using `Query.equal()` like this such as the overall number of characters when JSON encoded ([~4096 chars](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/blob/60f66fe826bfaa3083b9b04ee3416ee83b4f0865/app/controllers/api/databases.php#L2952C62-L2952C62)) and possibly the number of elements (possibly 100, but I don't recall).

That said, if you were building out something like Twitter with a feed system, you might need to design some more complex logic that prevents one user from filling up someone's feed, so this more complex design probably wouldn't be using this type of simple filter.

Comment: Thanks mate, thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I never thought of the last part, would do that as well